# MATLAB - Plotting random points in a circle using a congruential RNG

Tags: matlab, plot

I am aiming at plotting some random numbers in a circle using MATLAB. My code:

```
c = 3; p = 31; x = [7];

% generating random numbers (z) in the range [0,1) using 
% congruential random number generator (multiplicative)

for i = 2:200;
x(i) = mod(c*x(i-1),p);
end;
z = x/p;

% plot unit circle
hold on;
theta = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
plot(cos(theta),sin(theta),'.');
hold off;

% plotting random points in the unit circle using in-built rand function
phi = 2*pi*rand(1,200);
r = 1*sqrt(rand(1,200));

% plotting random points using the RNG above
% phi = 2*pi*z;
% r = 1*sqrt(z);

hold on;
x = 0 + r.*cos(phi);
y = 0 + r.*sin(phi);
plot(x,y,'r*');
hold off;
clear;
```

The problem I am facing is that both `z` and `rand` consist of random numbers in the range [0,1). However, when I plot using `rand` I get the ideal result - 
[image]

while `z` gives me a helix sorta thing - 
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: You related both `phi` and `r` to `z` in a one-to-one mapping, i.e. each `z` results in a fixed `phi` and `r`, this results in a non random plot. I also suspect your congruential RNG is not so random. If you'd create `z=rand(1,200)` in your first solution, I think you'd also obtain a non-random graph

Comment: Thanks! The problem did lie there. I used two different random sequences for `phi` and `r` and it seems to work fine. 
Also, yes, my RNG is far from practical. I'll try to better it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy! Your random number generator is good to some excent.

Random number generators based on prime division do generally have a period. After a number of samples they repeat themselves.

In your case, try to `plot(z)`

[image]

You will notice that that set of numbers is periodic, and has a period of 31. Coincidence?

**I THINK NOT!**

Thus, remember that when you want to generate pseudorandom numbers, you need a `p` bigger than the amount of samples you want to generate.

For example if we choose another set of coprime numbers to generate `z`

```
c = 991; p = 997;
```

The `plot(z)` will be:

[image]

And the final plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Ander! I figured as much from Adriaan's comment on the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Besides Ander's good point about the RNG there is also the problem of using `z` for both `phi` and `r`. Check it by using `z=rand(200,1)` and then creating your plot:
[image: helixcircle]

gives the same result as you had before. If you let `z` be different for both, you get "true" randomness, to some extend in your RNG. I used this RNG:

```
c = 991;
p = 997;
x=zeros(400,1);
x(1,1) = 7;
for ii = 2:400;
    x(ii,1) = mod(c*x(ii-1),p);
end;
z = x/p;
phi2 = 2*pi*z(1:200,1);
r2 = 1*sqrt(z(201:400,1));
```

where I let your RNG run a bit longer and then used the first 200 for `phi` and the last 200 for `r`:

[image: semi-rand circle]

As you can see there's still some kind of swirl visible, but that's due to your RNG. The larger you pick your `c` and `p` the less that will be.

Just to show you how pretty your RNG becomes by setting `c=3` and `p=31` and using the full 400 range of `z` as above. Isn't that a great swirl?

[image: Swirly]